# Angular Material - mdContent doesn't scroll properly

Tags: angular-material

I'm using angular material to create a page with a fixed toolbar on the top and a md-content next to the toolbar. However I can't make the toolbar sticky. I've read the documentation for many times, it should be simply like:

```
<body layout="column">
    <md-toolbar>
    ...
    </md-toolbar>

    <md-content>
    ...
    </md-content>
</body>
```

and md-content should be set as `overflow: auto` already. But just like the first example in the documentation, even I set `overflow` to `scroll`. It still doesn't work.

Please see the [codepen](http://codepen.io/vincentf06/pen/grBYEq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your height on the element that needs to be scrolled or else it won't know what portion needs to scroll.

```
<md-content flex="" layout-padding="" style="overflow: auto; height: 200px;">
```

Comment: It works, thank you. But how can I make md-content to fit the height of browser automatically?

Comment: if you don't give a div (which is what md-content breaks out into), it will take up whatever the necessary height it needs to display its content (even if that content is not visible on screen, hence the need to scroll). If you don't set the height, the div will shrink/grow to accommodate whatever is inside it. It doesn't take in to account how much "screen" is visible without some other things being set first. You can use the new CSS3 viewport-percentage (supported in most modern browsers) to make it as dynamic as possible: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths